# Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{n^2 + 1} = 0$ using definition of a limit.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Here's what I have so far:

By definition we have $\epsilon$$>0$, and so $\frac{n}{n^2+1}$$-0<$$\epsilon$.

Then,

$$\frac{n}{n^2+1} < \frac{n}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$$

for all $n\geq1$.

What would be my next step here?

Comment: Your last line holds for all $n>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$. So, you may pick $n_{0}$ to be the smallest integer greater than $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ by the [Archimedean Property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) such that $\frac{1}{n_0} < \epsilon$. Then

$$ n > n_0 \implies \frac{n}{n^2 + 1} < \frac{n}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{n_0} <\epsilon$$

Done.

Comment: If you have any question feel free to ask.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, and I remember doing something similar on another problem now. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of limit, you need to prove following:

For any $ϵ$, there is a N, such that, for all $n > N$

$$\dfrac{{n}} {{n^2+1}} <ϵ$$

Take $N=\left\lfloor\dfrac1{ε}\right\rfloor$,  for all $n>N$, there is
$$
\dfrac{{n}} {{n^2+1}} <\dfrac{1} {{n}}<\dfrac{1} {{N}}<ϵ
$$